# how to filter all those records(resource model) which dont have specific PROJECT

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Basically i have PROJECT model and RESOURCE model. PROJECT have many RESOURCES and RESOURCE have many PROJECTS (many-to-many relationship).
So i wants to peekAll or filter RESOURCES that are not belongs to my PROJECT.
something like that:

```
this.store.filter('resource', function(resource){
resource.get('projects') != this.get('project')
})
```

it should be something like that. i dont know what would be correct way.
i just wants to fetch those resources who dont have this.get('project') or specific project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combo `peekAll` and `rejectBy`.

```
var resourcesThatDoNotBelongToMyProject = this.get('store').peekAll('resources').rejectBy('projects', this.get('project'));
```

Note the opposite of `rejectBy` is `findBy`

Comment: its not working in my case. i think the reason that i have many projects on single resource. it will work if i have single project on a single resource. like that 
**rejectBy('project', this.get('project'))**
i also check relationships between resources and projects. these are many to many and relations are working properly in ember inspector. 
no doubt its good answer but its not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

it will return all those active resources that do not belongs to my `project`

```
 resourcesThatDoNotBelongToMyProject: Ember.computed('resources',function(){
        var _self = this;
        return this.get('resources').filter(function(resource){
           let not_present=true;
           if(resource.get('projects') != undefined) {
               resource.get('projects').forEach(function (project) {
                   if (project.id  == _self.get('model').id) {
                       not_present = false;
                   }
               });
           }
            if(not_present == true) {
                return resource.get("active") == true
            }
       });
    }),
```